# Difference between "counts" and "number of observations" in matplotlib histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

The matplotlib.pyplot.hist() documentation describes the parameter "density" (its deprecated name was "normed") as:

> > density : bool, optional
> >
> > > If True, the first element of the return tuple will be the counts normalized to form a probability density, i.e., the area (or integral) under the histogram will sum to 1. This is achieved by dividing the count by the number of observations times the bin width and not dividing by the total number of observations.

With the first element of the tuple it refers to the y-axis values. It says that it manages to get the *area* under the histogram to be 1 by: **dividing the *count* by the *number of observations* times the bin width.**

What is the difference between ***count*** and ***number of observations***? In my head they are the same thing: the number of instances (or number of counts or number of observations) the variable value falls into a certain bin. However, this would mean that the transformed number of counts for each bin is just one over the bin width (since # / #*bin_width = 1/bin_width) which does not make any sense.

Could someone clarify this for me? Thank you for your help and sorry for the probably stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the wording in the documentation is a bit confusing. The count is the number of entries in a given bin (height of the bin) and the number of observation is the total number of events that go into the histogram.

The documentation makes the distinction about how they normalized because there are generally two ways to do the normalization:

- `count / number of observations` - in this case if you add up all the entries of the output array you would get `1`.
- `count / (number of observations * bin width)` - in this case the **integral** of the output array is `1` so it is a true probability density. This is what `matplotlib` does, and they just want to be clear in this distinction.

Comment: Please feel free to adjust the wording if you have a good idea about it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58834452/how-does-matplotlib-calculate-the-density-for-historgram/58839258#58839258) shows another problem with the exact same sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The count of all obervations is the number of observations. But with a histogram you're interested in the counts *per bin*. So for each bin you divide the count of this bin by the total number of observations times the bin width.

```
import numpy as np

observations = [1.2, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 2.2, 2.3, 3.6, 4.1, 4.2, 4.4]
bin_edges = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

counts, edges = np.histogram(observations, bins=bin_edges)
print(counts)   # prints [0 4 2 1 3]

density, edges = np.histogram(observations, bins=bin_edges, density=True)
print(density)  # prints [0.  0.4 0.2 0.1 0.3]

# calculate density manually according to formula
man_density = counts/(len(observations)*np.diff(edges))
print(man_density)   # prints [0.  0.4 0.2 0.1 0.3]

# Check that density == manually calculated density
assert(np.all(man_density == density))
```